# How to click on an element identical to another element using selenium in python?

Tags: python, selenium, modal-dialog, z-index, webdriverwait

I want to click on a button element which is identical to another button element on the same page but one is in the front and one is at the back(see pic). how can I do this?
the first x button's html code is like:

```
 <div id="ModalPopAmityHostel" class="modal fade in" role="dialog" aria-hidden="false" style="display: block;">
        <div class="modal-dialog " style="z-index:104546464; ">

            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Amity Hostel</h4>
                </div>
```

second x button's html code is:

```
<div id="StudentSatisfactionPop" class="modal fade in" role="dialog" aria-hidden="false" style="display: block; padding-right: 15px;">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">STUDENT SATISFACTION SURVEY </h4>
            </div>
```

this is my code using selenium in python:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

chromedriver = "/usr/share/chromedriver/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
driver.maximize_window()
#wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 1)
driver.get("https://student.amizone.net")
# 3 | type | name=_UserName | 7071804 | 
driver.find_element(By.NAME, "_UserName").send_keys("username")
# 4 | type | name=_Password | 62ae6f | 
driver.find_element(By.NAME, "_Password").send_keys("password")
# 9 | click | css=#loginform .login100-form-btn |  | 
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#loginform .login100-form-btn").click()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "close").click()
```

it gives this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "amizone_automated_login.py", line 36, in <module>
    driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "close").click()
  File "/home/manik/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 80, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "/home/manik/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/home/manik/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/manik/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=79.0.3945.88)
```

this is the page:[image]

I think the error is coming because it's clicking the x button behind the pop-up because it comes first in the html script. is there a way of clicking the x button in the front?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of direct fetching the element by `classname` you should fetch the using by `id` in the xpath because `id` of both the windows are different.
You can close the first window by using:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@id='ModalPopAmityHostel']//button[@class='close']").click()
```

And after clicking on first Close button you can click on the second close button in the similar fashion, you just need to replace id by `StudentSatisfactionPop`

Answer (score 0):

### z-index

The [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) CSS property specifies the stack order of an element. An element with greater stack order is always in front of an element with a lower stack order. So overlapping elements with a larger z-index cover those with a smaller one.

---

Comparing both the HTMLs you have provided the following element have a larger z-index and hence covers the other element.

```
<div id="ModalPopAmityHostel" class="modal fade in" role="dialog" aria-hidden="false" style="display: block;">
    <div class="modal-dialog " style="z-index:104546464; ">
```

So you need to identify and click the <kbd>**x**</kbd> button of the above mentioned element first.

---

### Solution

As the desired element is a [Modal Dialog Box](https://www.w3schools.com/Bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp) so to locate and `click()` on the desired element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#ModalPopAmityHostel div.modal-content>div.modal-header>button.close[data-dismiss='modal']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='ModalPopAmityHostel']//div[@class='modal-content']/div[@class='modal-header']/button[@class='close' and @data-dismiss='modal']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```